# Create network namespace that doesn't use global tunnel (VPN) interface

Tags: linux, vpn, namespace

My understanding of what `ip netns` does (and general networking) is fuzzy, so maybe what I'm asking for isn't even possible.

So, what I have.  Three global interfaces, let's call them `lo`, `eth0` and `tun0`.  `eth0` is used to access Internet, `tun0` is an interface created by `openconnect` for the purpose of connecting to company's VPN.

For reasons I don't understand<sup>1</sup>, some company's resources are only accessible when the machine is **not** connected to VPN.  I've established this by killing `openconnect` process, which subsequently removed the `tun0` interface.

What I hoped to be able to achieve:

1. Create a dedicated `novpn` namespace.
2. Create virtual interface pair `veth0` and `veth1`.
3. Configure `veth0` to handle addresses of `eth0`.
4. Add `veth0` to `novpn` namespace.
5. Run browser using something like `ip netns exec novpn firefox`.

But it didn't do what I expected.  The browser run in such a way was still able to access VPN network resources.

So, is it even possible to create two namespaces, one that is connected to VPN and the other one that isn't?

---

<sup>1</sup> - It is trying to access a third-party authentication provider, but, probably, the resource being accessed is different based on whether the machine is connected to VPN or not, or maybe it's looking for the source IP in the outgoing traffic... your guess is as good as any.

Comment: You may not need network namespaces for this. You can probably get what you want by just updating your routing tables. The keyword you're probably looking for is [split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

Comment: @igal thank you for the hint, I will need to read more about it!

Comment: Sure. Good luck. I'll be back after work if you don't get this resolved by then.

Comment: Also, you might want to update your question to include the output of `ifconfig` and `route` (or `ip addr` and `ip route`). If some of that information is sensitive then you can just edit it or mock it up to use some place-holder information that people can refer to in their solutions.

Comment: Depending on how you did (3), probably the packets from the `novpn` just followed the default route, which is through the tunnel. Have a look at `macvlan` if you want a second virtual ethernet device (with different IP address) that connects to your LAN (and therefore to the internet). Also, please edit question and describe *what kinds of applications* need tunnel/no tunnel access, and to which addresses - there may be easier ways of implementing this.